# How to hide certain content types from a Link field

Tags: 8, nodes

I created a content type for my slides in a carousel. I make a view to print them all and everything works perfectly. My only problem is that I have multiple use of the Link field from core and the auto-complete form spits out my slides node and my other nodes. How can I limit which node type are shown in all Link field? It doesn't matter if it's site-wide as they will never be needed in those fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that D8 core link field will always look for all content types. You have to write custom javascript to filter it I believe. To make life easier, I would try [Link Field Autocomplete Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_field_autocomplete_filter), but personally I like [Linkit](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit) module much more for its ability to integrate with media.